# Error(3;0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'

Tags: java, android, gradle

```
Error:(3, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'
Possible causes:The project 'PayBillet' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
 The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
```

Чем может быть вызвана данная ошибка и как её исправить?

Прикрепляю gradle файл модуля

```
configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('sqljdbc42.jar'))
android {
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все просто, ответ уже был тут: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27735956/5834068
Если по-русски:
Проверьте, последние ли у Вас версии Gradle и Android studio

> https://www.gradle.org/
>
> http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility

1. Измените файл build.gradle:

   ```
   buildscript {
       repositories {
           mavenCentral()
       }   

    dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
       }
   }

   allprojects {
       repositories {
           mavenCentral()
       }
   }
   ```
2. Отредактируйте файл app/build.gradle:

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   android {
       compileSdkVersion 23
       buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'



    defaultConfig {
           minSdkVersion 9
           targetSdkVersion 23
           versionCode 1
           versionName '1.0'
       }

   }

   dependencies {
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
   }
   ```
3. И запустите Gradle

   ```
     gradle installDebug
   ```